# how to resolve all symlinks in a directory?

Tags: scripts, packaging

I'm trying to make a debian package from upstream source code which is not mine. The `configure` script provided by author makes a lot of symlinks in source directory. They're symlinks to all headers in `src` subdir to `include` subdir (So that makefile can easily copy the `include` directory in the case of installing development package). I'm using `debhelper` scripts to make package.

I'm using `debhelper` scripts to make package. The problem is using new debian package format (`quilt 3.0 native`), `debuild` refuses add changes of source directory consisting symlinks to final `diff` file. I'm getting errors like this:

```
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to foo.h:
dpkg-source: error:   new version is symlink to /ba/foo/foo.h
dpkg-source: error:   old version is nonexistent
```

I'm aware of the good solution: Change configure script not to symlink any header at all. It should add a target to `makefile` to install `devel` package. Though configure script has copyright issues. I can't touch upstream source.

I'm looking for a bash script to replace all symlinks in a directory with actual files they point to. For example if in the directory `d` there are three files `a` and `b` and `c`, which they ate symlinks to `../../foo/bar/x`, `../../foo/bar/z` `../../foo/bar/y`, running desired script (say `magic.sh`) giving the `./d` as first argument, should

```
cp ../../foo/bar/x ./d/a
cp ../../foo/bar/y ./d/b
cp ../../foo/bar/z ./d/c
```

I can't find a way to know which file is a symlink pointing to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `readlink`.

```
$ readlink /etc/alternatives/editor
/usr/bin/vim.basic
```

and wrap it in a shell script walking over the symbolic links in the directory.

You can find symbolic links using `find`:

```
$ find . -type l
```

A more complete example:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -type l | while read LINE; do 
echo link: $LINE resolved: `readlink $LINE`
done
```

outputs

```
link: ./.remmina resolved: sparkleshare-homedir/remmina
link: ./project resolved: Documents/2011-2 Project/
link: ./.ssh resolved: sparkleshare-homedir/ssh
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FNWQAsbm I hope this work for me...

Comment: Be sure to do proper escaping though when doing operations. A symlink resolving to ``bla / bla`` may expand to this: ``rm -rf bla / bla``. Not sure if your example prevents this, mine doesn't.